# How to transform SQL table of data into table of pointers?

Tags: sql, sqlite, rdbms

Let's say I have an SQL table of tuples (id, lastname, firstname, occupation) where all values are strings (ok, obviously *id* is a key).

I want to transform it to a table with tuples (id, lastid, firstid, occupid), where I only keep pointers to other tables that contain the actual values. I apologize if the example domain of names and occupations is not the best suited for this operation.

Obviously to create the other tables that will hold the data, I need to get all last names, unique, and insert them into a new table with an auto-generated key. The same with first names and occupations.

Having done that, is there a single transformation that can generate the new table containing the pointers (er, foreign keys) ?

Implementation uses SQLite, if it matters.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Do you have lots of repetition in the data? The whole approach seems a bit odd to me...

Comment: Agreed, this definitively sounds like really bad normalization in the base data...

Comment: Yes, lots of repetition in original data.  Think millions of rows, only thousands (not even tens of thousands) of different values. I'll be the first to point out that the example domain chosen above is not one immediately applicable...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tables for last/first names and occupations are Lnt, Fnt and Occ, each with just two columns, an id field and a value:

```
REPLACE INTO TheTable (last, first, occup)
SELECT Lnt.id, Fnt.id, Occ.id
FROM TheTable
JOIN Lnt ON (last=Lnt.value)
JOIN Fnt ON (first=Fnt.value)
JOIN Occ ON (occup=Occ.value)
```